# update problem on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: updates, update-manager

While entering the command `sudo apt-get update` on terminal (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), I got an error message at the end which says :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: The address you provided look valid and contains all the required entries. Can you try the command `sudo apt-get update` once again? Are you behind some proxy?

Comment: No..I am not using any proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you either have an internet connectivity problem or a DNS issue as what the system is looking for is clearly there as can be seen [here.](http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release)